# Call correct method from Controller (MVC, RAZOR)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, razor, controller

I have **BooksController** with method *Get*:

```
[HttpGet]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string name)
{
    @books = await _booksService.BrowseAsync(name);
    return View("books",@books);
}
```

and view **books.cshtml**:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebPart.Infrastructure.DTO.BooksDto>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
        </td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "get", new { id = item.Id })
        <br />
    </tr>
}
```

When I tried to "click" link "Edit" I have problem two run my second get method and open view **edit**:

```
[HttpGet("{booksId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(Guid booksId)
{
    var @books = await _booksService.GetAsync(booksId);
    return View("edit", @books);            
}
```

These two metod *GET* are in the same *BooksController*.

What I'm doing wrong here? Because it's always running the first *GET* method.

Comment: Partly a guess, but it's expecting a parameter called `booksId` and you're sending one called `id`.  Match those up?

Comment: yes, I see link like: *Books?id=a40ab714-b96e-40db-a55e-e853bdf16a87*, but it should run *_booksService.GetAsync* and view *edit* need to be open

Comment: Right, and what happens when you send a parameter called `booksId` instead of `id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller action is expecting a parameter called `booksId`:

```
[HttpGet("{booksId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(Guid booksId)
```

You're sending a parameter called `id`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "get", new { id = item.Id })
```

The names need to match.  If the parameter needs to be called `booksId`, call it `booksId`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "get", new { booksId = item.Id })
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
[HttpGet("{booksId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(Guid booksId)
{
    var @books = await Task.Run(() => _booksService(booksId));
    return View("edit", @books);            
}
```